# Combo box in view based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view based NSTableView set up. It uses a datasource and NOT bindings. I have the protocol all set up right and it works if I use a text field. However I'm trying to change the last column into a combo box. I think I need to use an custom NSTableCellView but I'm not really sure how to do that. Any help on how to set it up would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you have your NSTableView delegate set, hopefully you have a corresponding [`tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3adataCellForTableColumn%3arow%3a) method to go with it.

If you do, then giving it a combo box might be as easy as creating an IBOutlet pointing to a NSCell object with a combo box dropped into it.

And when that `dataCellForTableColumn` method is called and the `NSTableColumn` is equal to the column you want to return the combo box for, then return that special NSCell.

How does that sound so far?

Comment: That sounds like its for a cell based table. I'm working with a view based table introduced in 10.7.

Comment: Would have been nice if you had mentioned that fact in your original question. But in any event, you can now use the NSTableViewDelegate method [`tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:) method to pass back a view that has a Combo Box as a subview.  How about that?  :-)

Comment: Can't try it out right now, but that sounds like what I want. Also, look at the first sentence of the original question.

Comment: ahhh, I didn't see that (and guess I need stronger glasses).  Let me know if the method I pointed you to solves the issue!

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize I already had that method implemented. And here is the code that I was trying to make it work with
`if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Assigned"]) {
        NSComboBox *comboBox = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:identifier];
        [comboBox addItemWithObjectValue:@"Mark"];
        [comboBox addItemWithObjectValue:@"Will"];
        comboBox.objectValue = value;
        return comboBox;
    }`